# Mutual connections in Strapi

Tags: connection, strapi

Here's something I cannot understand about kind of mutual connections and how to realize it the best way.
Let's imagine Tinder.
There's an object `Human` with some properties (gender, age, name etc)
He likes some other `Humans` , other `Humans` likes him, that is ok, no problems.
The problem starts when I try to make the mutual connections.

What I want to get:
Object `Human` has a parameter that links to an object `Match`, that has 2 links: `human1` and `human2`

But it doesnt works.
Only second human has a correct link.

PLEASE
could you share your vision of the best way how to architect this need the best way, that both of humans has a correct link to Matches at the same parameter?

Example:
Humans:

```
[{
id: 1,
matches: [1]},
{
id: 2
matches: [1]
}]
```

Matches:

```
[
  { id: 1
    human1: 1,
    human2: 2
  }
]
```